# NoClassDefFoundError when using Apache CXF's wsdl2java -databinding jibx

Tags: maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, jibx

I am trying to generate Java code from wsdl using Apache CXF's wsdl2java tool. I downloaded the binary distribution from [here](http://cxf.apache.org/download.html) on windows and installed it using `mvn` command on CXF directory from command line.

It works fine with default binding JAXB. It also works when I use argument `-db xmlbeans`. However, when I use `-db jibx`, I get the following exception:

```
C:\Users\spagariya\apache-cxf-2.7.11>wsdl2java -db jibx mywsdl.wsdl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jibx/schema/validation/ProblemHandler
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.loadDataBindingProfile(PluginLoader.java:409)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getDataBindingProfile(PluginLoader.java:422)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadDataBinding(WSDLToJava.java:74)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jibx.schema.validation.ProblemHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 10 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have jibx-schema in your classpath. Check that you have downloaded this jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-schema</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The binary distribution does not have pom.xml. Although I do have the jar in .m2/repository

Comment: @ShreyansPagariya I tried it myself. But slight differently from you. I got the zip version of it and unzipped it. I got the same error as yours. Then I copied the two jars (Not pom) in the lib folder and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that copying jar files into the folder adds them into the classpath. However, on a different note, I am getting java heap space OutOfMemoryError now. I tried to increase it using `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M`, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind. I had to set the heap size inside the batch file. However, I am running into a similar issue. can you help me out with this [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IAdaptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820163/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-core-runtime-iadaptable)

Comment: Cool. Good it works for now. I was looking at the wsdl2java doc just for that. :)